# Coincidence of numbers of solutions of matrix equations $A^2=B^2$ and $AB=0$ of size 2 over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields, matrix-equations

Let ring $R:=M_2(\mathbb F_p)$, where prime $p\ne 2$. There are two interesting equations $A^2=B^2$ and $(A+B)(A-B)=0$, and the numbers of solution pairs $(A,B)\in R^2$ of the equations are denoted $S_1(p),S_2(p)$.

The fun fact is that, I used a computer search and found $S_1(p)=S_2(p)$ for very small $p$-s. Actually:
$$
S_1(3)=S_2(3)=417,\ S_1(5)=S_2(5)=4705,\ S_1(7)=S_2(7)=23233,\ S_1(11)=S_2(11)=202081. 
$$

And if we set $R:=M_2(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ **where $p$ may be a general odd number**, we even have $S_1(9)=S_2(9)=123201$. So $S_1=S_2$ seems to be true in some more general settings. But I can't find any patterns in these numbers $S_i$ by just looking at them or using an OEIS check.

Let's name the equations (1) and (2) respectively. For (1), I've tried to use $A=X+Y,B=X-Y$ to rewrite it as follows,
$$ (X+Y)^2=(X-Y)^2 \iff 2(XY+YX)=0, $$
since $R$ is not commutative. And by $p$ is odd, we eventually get $ab+ba=0$. And for (2), a similar argument reduce it to $XY=0$. But I still can't see how can one relate a solution of $XY+YX=0$ to a solution of $XY=0$. Is there any magic behind this?

Also, there would be no similar results for $M_3(\mathbb F_3)$, in that case $S_1=221157$ and $S_2=496341$.

---

**Update**

The above is the original problem. By a careful case-by-case discussion over the trace and rank of one of the matrix $X$ or $Y$, as suggested by the answer or the comment, we find the two equations $XY+YX=0$ and $XY=0$ both have $p^5+3p^4-2p^3-2p^2+p$ solutions.

But there are similar and more shocking phenomena: for a positive integer $n>0$, the following equation
$$
f_n(X,Y)=XY-YX-X^n=0
$$
always seems to have $2p^4-p^2$ solutions no matter what $n$ is, coprime to $p$ or not. This [sequence](https://oeis.org/A002593) is OEIS $\mathsf A2593$. But there seems to be nothing related to our problem on that link page.

---

**Another Update**

Thanks to @user1551. For the new equation $f_n(X,Y)=0$ when $n\ge 2$, there is now some shortcut to see the result by linear algebra.
By the fact that $[X,Y]$ commutes with $X$ (since $[X,Y]=X^n$), **Jacobson's Lemma** implies that $[X,Y]$ is nilpotent and $X$ is nilpotent too under our field characteristic condition. Because $X\in R$ is a $2\times 2$ nilpotent matrix, we have $X^n=0$ when $n\ge 2$. So solution sets for $n\ge 2$ are the same since $f_n(X,Y)=0$ iff $[X,Y]=0$ and $X$ is nilpotent.

When $n=1$, we know now $[X,Y]=X$ is nilpotent. Notice that this equation has at least one solution $Y_0$ for each given nilpotent $X$ (consider $X$ to be a Jordan form and construct $Y$ directly). After $Y\mapsto Y+Y_0$, equation $[X,Y_0+Y]=X$ becomes $[X,Y]=0$. This build a correspondence between the $n=1$ case and the $n\ge 2$ case.

Comment: I don't know how to obtain a solution to one equation from a solution to the other, but if we count the solutions directly, we can see that $S_1$ is indeed equal to $S_2$ over any finite field of odd order $q$. They are both equal to $(q-1)^2(q+1)^3+2q^4-1$.

Comment: The result for your new equation isn’t really that surprising. When $n\ge2$ and $f_n(X,Y)=0$, we have $X^n=[X,Y]$. Therefore $X$ commutes with $[X,Y]$. Since $p\ge2$, the dimension of $X$, we conclude by [Jacobson’s lemma](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(80)90196-9) that $[X,Y]$ is nilpotent. As $X^n=[X,Y]$, $X$ is nilpotent too. It follows that $X^n=0$ when $n\ge2$. Thus $(X,Y)$ is a solution if and only if $X$ is nilpotent and $[X,Y]=0$, and the cardinality of this solution set is $2p^4-p^2$.

Comment: When $X$ is nilpotent but nonzero, it is similar to $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$. So, $Y$ is similar (via the same similarity transform) to $\pmatrix{a&b\\ 0&a+1}$ when $n=1$ and to $\pmatrix{a&b\\ 0&a}$ when $n\ge2$. Therefore, for each choice of nilpotent $X\ne0$, the number of solutions $Y$ are the same (namely, $p^2$) regardless of $n=1$ or $n\ge2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just compute the number of pairs $(a,b)$ with $ab=0$, $a,b\in M_2(F_p)$.
Every nonzero matrix $M_2(F_p)$ with determinant $0$ is similar to one of the matrices
$$
u=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\
v=\begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha & 0 \\
  0      & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\alpha\in F_p$ and $\alpha\neq0$.
For brevity, let $G=GL_2(F_p)$. We have
$$
C_G(u)=\{g\in G\mid gu=ug\}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  \beta & \gamma \\
  0 & \beta
\end{pmatrix}\mid \beta\in F^*,\gamma\in F_p
\right\},
$$
$$
C_G(v)=\{g\in G\mid gv=vg\}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  \beta & 0 \\
  0 & \gamma
\end{pmatrix}\mid \beta,\gamma\in F^*
\right\}.
$$
The number of matrices similar to the first of them is
$$
|G:C_G(u)|=\frac{|G|}{|C_G(u)|}=\frac{(p^2-1)(p^2-p)}{p(p-1)}=p^2-1.
$$
The number of matrices similar to $v$ is
$$
|G:C_G(v)|=\frac{|G|}{|C_G(v)|}=\frac{(p^2-1)(p^2-p)}{(p-1)^2}=p(p+1).
$$
Now we compute the number of matrices $y$ such that $uy=0$ and the same for $v$.
$$
A_u=\{y\in M_2(F_p)\mid uy=0\}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  \beta & \gamma \\
    0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\mid \beta,\gamma\in F_p
\right\}\Rightarrow\ |A_u|=p^2,
$$
$$
A_v=\{y\in M_2(F_p)\mid vy=0\}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
  \beta & \gamma
\end{pmatrix}\mid \beta,\gamma\in F_p
\right\}\Rightarrow\ |A_v|=p^2.
$$
It follows that the set $W=\{(x,y)\in M_2(F_p)\times M_2(F_p)\mid xy=0 \}$ has exactly
$$
|W|=(p^2-1)p^2+p(p+1)(p-1)p^2+p^4+(p^2-1)(p^2-p)\\=p^5+3p^4-2p^3-2p^2+p.
$$
elements.

The number of elements of the set
$$
W'=\{(x,y)\in M_2(F_p)\times M_2(F_p)\mid xy+yx=0\}. 
$$
is computed in the same way